# How to sum values in one row PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I have a problem sum all values in one row. The table's like this :

[image: 1]

How to sum all values like this?

[image: 2]

The Formula's like this :

```
column 2019 = 2019,
column 2020 = 2020 + column 2019,
column 2021 = 2021 + column 2020,
column 2022 = 2022 + column 2021,
column total = same as the previous column
```

My query :

```
SELECT 3 AS id,
    'Equity / Modal'::text AS title,
    COALESCE(sum(a."2019") OVER (ORDER BY a.transaction) , 0::numeric) AS "2019",
    COALESCE(sum(a."2020" + "2019") OVER (ORDER BY a.transaction), 0::numeric) AS "2020",
    COALESCE(sum(a."2021" + "2020") OVER (ORDER BY a.transaction), 0::numeric) AS "2021",
    COALESCE(sum(a."2022" + "2021") OVER (ORDER BY a.transaction), 0::numeric) AS "2022",
    COALESCE(sum("2022") OVER (ORDER BY a.transaction), 0::numeric) AS total
FROM vw_blm_dashboard_iurantransaksi_anggota a
WHERE a.transaction = 'SUBTOTAL';
```

Comment: This seems an awfully complicated query for a simple problem as you describe it.  Why not just ```select 3 id, 'Equity / modal'::text title, a."2019" as "2019", a."2019"+a."2020" as "2020", a."2019"+a."2020"+a."2021" as "2021" , a."2019"+a."2020"+a."2021" as "Total" from ........ ```.  ?

Comment: @BjarniRagnarsson umm, I've thought of that way. I just wanna know maybe there is another way that is better than that?